# Tail Call Optimization in XSLT/Saxon?

Tags: recursion, xslt, xpath, saxon, xslt-3.0

Can anyone explain why the below code gets a stack overflow?  I had hoped that Saxon would identify the template as tail recursive, and optimise it, allowing for a very large number of iterations - in reality it gets a stack overflow after ~1000 iterations.  I'm executing as per below:

```
me@server:~/dev$ java -classpath /usr/local/share/java/saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:recurse.xslt 
437
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ParameterSet.getIndex(ParameterSet.java:127)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContextMajor.useLocalParameter(XPathContextMajor.java:561)
        at EE_sequence_02125238280.process(file:/home/me/dev/recurse.xslt:23)
        at com.saxonica.ee.bytecode.CompiledExpression.process(CompiledExpression.java:84)
        at com.saxonica.ee.bytecode.ByteCodeCandidate.process(ByteCodeCandidate.java:143)
        at com.saxonica.ee.bytecode.ByteCodeCandidate.processLeavingTail(ByteCodeCandidate.java:178)
        at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.NamedTemplate.expand(NamedTemplate.java:263)
        at EE_sequence_02125238280.process(file:/home/me/dev/recurse.xslt:23)
and so on.....
```

I'm using Saxon-EE 9.8.0.15J.

I've tried using `<xsl:if>`, XPATH and functions, in several variations in place of the `<xsl:choose>` - but I get the same issue.

With `call-templates` I can actually find comments online suggesting this should work, with examples similar to mine below.  I wasn't 100% clear if functions or a recursive call inside an XPATH expression were supported, hence I've stuck with `call-templates` for this example.
Eg: [Recursive Loop XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709092/recursive-loop-xslt)

I guess I'm missing a trick - any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                                             
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"  exclude-result-prefixes="xs map">               

    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>                                                                                                                                                        

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">                                                                                                                                                                                     
        <xsl:variable name="freqs" select="unparsed-text-lines('input.txt', 'UTF-8')!xs:integer(.)"/>                                                                                                                              
        <xsl:message select="sum($freqs)"/>                                                                                                                                                                                        
        <xsl:variable name="hash" select="map{}" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                                                                
        <xsl:call-template name="find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                                                
            <xsl:with-param name="freqs" select="$freqs"/>                                                                                                                                                                         
            <xsl:with-param name="cs-hash" select="$hash"/>                                                                                                                                                                        
        </xsl:call-template>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    <xsl:template name="find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                                                         
        <xsl:param name="freqs" as="xs:integer*"/>                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <xsl:param name="cs-hash" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                                                                               
        <xsl:param name="cs" select="0" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                                          
        <xsl:param name="i" select="1" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                                           
        <xsl:variable name="new-cs" select="$cs + $freqs[$i]" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:variable name="new-i" select="if ($i >= count($freqs)) then 1 else $i + 1" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                          
        <xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            <xsl:when test="map:contains($cs-hash, $new-cs)">                                                                                                                                                                      
                <xsl:value-of select="$new-cs"/>                                                                                                                                                                                   
            </xsl:when>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            <xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                <xsl:call-template name="find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                                        
                    <xsl:with-param name="freqs" select="$freqs"/>                                                                                                                                                                 
                    <xsl:with-param name="cs-hash" select="map:put($cs-hash,$new-cs,true())"/>                                                                                                                                     
                    <xsl:with-param name="cs" select="$new-cs"/>                                                                                                                                                                   
                    <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$new-i"/>                                                                                                                                                                     
                </xsl:call-template>                                                                                                                                                                                               
            </xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        </xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**

For a bit of context the code finds the 2nd occurrence of a number in a cumulative sum sequence, generated from repeatedly cycling over a fixed set of integer `freqs`. The latest cumulative sum is `cs`, and a dictionary of past seen cumulative sums is built-up in `cs-hash`. `i` indexes `freq` as an cyclic index/counter.

If my approach is daft, I'm interested in other approaches too, but I'd still like to understand why this code cannot be optimised - even if there is a better approach.

**EDIT 2**

For completeness the function implementation using `xsl:choose`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                            
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:aoc2018="\
http://www.blah.co.uk/aoc2018" exclude-result-prefixes="xs map aoc2018">                                                                                                                          
    <!-- hint: java -classpath /usr/local/share/java/saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:01.xslt -->                                                                                     
    <xsl:function name="aoc2018:find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                
        <xsl:param name="freqs" as="xs:integer*"/>                                                                                                                                                
        <xsl:param name="cs-hash" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                                              
        <xsl:param name="cs" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                     
        <xsl:variable name="new-cs" select="$cs + $freqs[$i]" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                   
        <xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                              
            <xsl:when test="map:contains($cs-hash, $new-cs)">                                                                                                                                     
                <xsl:value-of select="$new-cs"/>                                                                                                                                                  
            </xsl:when>                                                                                                                                                                           
            <xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                       
                <xsl:variable name="new-i" select="if ($i >= count($freqs))                                                                                                                       
                                                   then 1                                                                                                                                         
                                                   else $i + 1" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                 
                <xsl:value-of select="aoc2018:find-repeated-cs($freqs, map:put($cs-hash,$new-cs,true()), $new-cs, $new-i)"/>                                                                      
            </xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                      
        </xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                             
    </xsl:function>                                                                                                                                                                               
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>                                                                                                                       
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:variable name="freqs" select="unparsed-text-lines('input.txt', 'UTF-8')!xs:integer(.)"/>                                                                                             
        <xsl:message select="sum($freqs)"/>                                                                                                                                                       
        <xsl:variable name="hash" select="map{}" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                               
        <xsl:message select="aoc2018:find-repeated-cs($freqs, $hash, 0, 1)"/>                                                                                                                     
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                               
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the function implementation using an XPATH:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                            
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:aoc2018="\
http://www.blah.co.uk/aoc2018" exclude-result-prefixes="xs map aoc2018">                                                                                                                          
    <!-- hint: java -classpath /usr/local/share/java/saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:01.xslt -->                                                                                     
    <xsl:function name="aoc2018:find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                
        <xsl:param name="freqs" as="xs:integer*"/>                                                                                                                                                
        <xsl:param name="cs-hash" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                                              
        <xsl:param name="cs" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                     
        <xsl:variable name="new-cs" select="$cs + $freqs[$i]" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                   
        <xsl:variable name="new-i" select="if ($i >= count($freqs))                                                                                                                               
                                                   then 1                                                                                                                                         
                                                   else $i + 1" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                 
        <xsl:value-of select="if (map:contains($cs-hash, $new-cs))                                                                                                                                
                              then $new-cs                                                                                                                                                        
                              else aoc2018:find-repeated-cs($freqs, map:put($cs-hash,$new-cs,true()), $new-cs, $new-i)"/>                                                                         
    </xsl:function>                                                                                                                                                                               
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>                                                                                                                       
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:variable name="freqs" select="unparsed-text-lines('input.txt', 'UTF-8')!xs:integer(.)"/>                                                                                             
        <xsl:message select="sum($freqs)"/>                                                                                                                                                       
        <xsl:variable name="hash" select="map{}" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                               
        <xsl:message select="aoc2018:find-repeated-cs($freqs, $hash, 0, 1)"/>                                                                                                                     
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                               
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As you use XSLT 3, I would say the right attempt to avoid a StackOverflowError and to ensure "tail call optimization" is to use `xsl:iterate`. I am also not quite sure what you want to achieve, whether a fold-left or some adjacent grouping is not an easier way. It would help if you explain which computation the code is supposed to perform.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - thanks, will take a look at `xsl:iterate` - I've added some detail to the original question at the bottom describing what is supposed to be happening.  The code correctly generates the cumulative sums right up until it throws for stack overflow.

Comment: But is the recursion suppposed to ever stop for any input set? Are you not summing up values again and again, even for simple sequences like `1,2,3`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - it won't stop for every input set, but will for certain sets. This is an old Advent of Code problem - the example input set is available here https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1/input - my working implementations in various languages can be seen here https://github.com/falloutphil/aoc_2018/tree/master/day_01 - the Python one is the easiest to understand, the R one is closest to the XSLT above. The XSLT implementation matches the output of the working implementations (until the stack overflow). I'm aware that XSLT is not the perfect language for this, I'm enjoying the challenge!

Comment: I get a StackOverflowError for the input `1,2,3` with 9.8 EE but not with 9.9EE, but they just keep running until a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". It might help if you provide some more details of the input set you use and whether you exepct it to stop or not, not sure about the Saxon problem, only that 9.8 usually doesn't get fixes anymore as 9.9 is considered the stable release.

Comment: Ah, thanks again - I'll take a look at 9.9EE too.  In the example data I give in comment above it should terminate after just under 150,000 iterations.  Although I have never got beyond 1000 so haven't fully tested that condition - should work tho!

Comment: The file https://github.com/falloutphil/aoc_2018/blob/master/day_01/input.txt seems to work fine with your code in 9.8 HE, 9.9 HE and 9.9 EE so I guess it seems to be a problem in 9.8 EE with byte code compilation turned on. Let's wait whether Saxonica/Michael Kay sees the thread and considers it a bug to fix.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes confirmed on 9.9.1.5EE it works fine - but only for the named template solution given.  Recursing in my other implementations - using a function with a similar implementation to the template using `xsl:choose`, or by putting the recursive call into an xpath still gets a stack overflow.  I'm guessing only named templates implement the optimisation.

Comment: Just on `xsl:iterate` it looks like this must be provided an input sequence, so unless there is a way of repeatedly cycling over an input sequence in XSLT and relying on the `xsl:break` to terminate, I'm not sure it can be used to solve recursion problems where the range of the input is unknown at the start? https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#iterate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed that this works (with tail recursion) under 9.9, with or without bytecode generation enabled, but under 9.8 it succeeds only if bytecode generation is switched off. I think the difference between the releases is that 9.9 is smarter at deciding not to use bytecode generation in cases where it would interfere with tail recursion.

To see why it fails when using function calls rather than templates I would need to see the code. The two cases use different mechanisms internally. In particular functions are by default evaluated in "pull" mode (they return an iterator over the result), templates in "push" mode (they write results out to a result tree). The most noticeable difference is that returning a sequence containing the result of a recursive call (for example `select="$x, f:myself($x - 1)`) can be done tail-recursively with templates, but not with functions. But that doesn't seem to apply to your case. Also, for templates we handle mutual recursion of two or more templates, while with functions we only handle self-recursion.

The following version appears to work using tail-recursion using either 9.8 or 9.9, with or without bytecode generation. (Under 9.8, though, there is an oddity which I haven't had time to investigate: after producing the output value, the process doesn't actually exit.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                                             
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:f="f" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">               

    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="limit" select="2000"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">                                                                                                                                                                                     
        <xsl:variable name="freqs" select="1 to $limit"/>                                                                                                                              
        <xsl:message select="sum($freqs)"/>                                                                                                                                                                                        
        <xsl:variable name="hash" select="map{}" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>   
        <xsl:sequence select="f:find-repeated-cs($freqs, $hash, 0, 1)"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    </xsl:template>                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    <xsl:function name="f:find-repeated-cs">                                                                                                                                                                                         
        <xsl:param name="freqs" as="xs:integer*"/>                                                                                                                                                                                 
        <xsl:param name="cs-hash" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>                                                                                                                                                               
        <xsl:param name="cs" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                                          
        <xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                                           
        <xsl:variable name="new-cs" select="$cs + $freqs[$i]" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                                                    
        <xsl:variable name="new-i" select="if ($i >= count($freqs)) then 1 else $i + 1" as="xs:integer"/>                                                                                                                          
        <xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            <xsl:when test="map:contains($cs-hash, $new-cs)">                                                                                                                                                                      
                <xsl:value-of select="$new-cs"/>                                                                                                                                                                                   
            </xsl:when>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            <xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                <xsl:sequence select="f:find-repeated-cs($freqs, map:put($cs-hash,$new-cs,true()), $new-cs, $new-i)"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            </xsl:otherwise>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        </xsl:choose>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    </xsl:function>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, when I say it works, I mean it doesn't fail with a stack overflow. Further checking reveals that it doesn't actually terminate - it seems the termination condition is never true. I haven't tried to work out why.

In your code, you have used `<xsl:value-of>` to return the function result, rather than `xsl:sequence`. `xsl:value-of` delivers a text node, which needs to be constructed from the result of the recursive call: you can see this in the -explain output:

```
<function name="Q{http://www.blah.co.uk/aoc2018}find-repeated-cs"
              line="5"
              module="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsl"
              eval="9"
              flags="pU"
              as="item()*"
              slots="6">
      <arg name="Q{}freqs" as="xs:integer*"/>
      <arg name="Q{}cs-hash" as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)"/>
      <arg name="Q{}cs" as="xs:integer"/>
      <arg name="Q{}i" as="xs:integer"/>
      <let role="body"
           baseUri="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsl"
           ns="xsl=~ aoc2018=http://www.blah.co.uk/aoc2018 xs=~ map=~"
           line="10"
           var="Q{}new-cs"
           as="xs:integer"
           slot="4"
           eval="16">
        <check card="1" diag="3|0|XTTE0570|new-cs">
          <arith op="+" calc="i+i">
            <varRef name="Q{}cs" slot="2"/>
            <subscript>
              <varRef name="Q{}freqs" slot="0"/>
              <varRef name="Q{}i" slot="3"/>
            </subscript>
          </arith>
        </check>
        <let line="13" var="Q{}new-i" as="xs:integer" slot="5" eval="16">
          <choose>
            <vc op="ge" onEmpty="0" comp="CAVC">
              <varRef name="Q{}i" slot="3"/>
              <fn name="count">
                <varRef name="Q{}freqs" slot="0"/>
              </fn>
            </vc>
            <int val="1"/>
            <true/>
            <arith op="+" calc="i+i">
              <varRef name="Q{}i" slot="3"/>
              <int val="1"/>
            </arith>
          </choose>
          <valueOf line="16">
            <fn name="string-join">
              <convert from="xs:anyAtomicType" to="xs:string">
                <choose>
                  <ifCall name="Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map}contains"
                          type="xs:boolean">
                    <varRef name="Q{}cs-hash" slot="1"/>
                    <varRef name="Q{}new-cs" slot="4"/>
                  </ifCall>
                  <varRef name="Q{}new-cs" slot="4"/>
                  <true/>
                  <data>
                    <mergeAdj>
                      <ufCall name="Q{http://www.blah.co.uk/aoc2018}find-repeated-cs"
                              tailCall="false"
                              bSlot="0"
                              eval="6 16 6 6">
                        <varRef name="Q{}freqs" slot="0"/>
                        <treat as="map(xs:integer, xs:boolean)" diag="0|1||aoc2018:find-repeated-cs">
                          <ifCall name="Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map}put" type="map(*)">
                            <varRef name="Q{}cs-hash" slot="1"/>
                            <varRef name="Q{}new-cs" slot="4"/>
                            <true/>
                          </ifCall>
                        </treat>
                        <varRef name="Q{}new-cs" slot="4"/>
                        <varRef name="Q{}new-i" slot="5"/>
                      </ufCall>
                    </mergeAdj>
                  </data>
                </choose>
              </convert>
              <str val=" "/>
            </fn>
          </valueOf>
        </let>
      </let>
    </function>
```

Because further operations need to be performed with the function result (namely, converting it to a text node, which involves atomizing the result, converting the items in the result to strings, and separating them with spaces) the function is not tail-recursive. Always use `xsl:sequence` to return a function result, and always declare the result type of the function and the types of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay - I've added to versions of the code to the question using function+xsl:choose and function+XPATH - neither of these seem to work in 9.9?

Comment: Also in the above so I'm sure - what you've demonstrated is that by providing an arbitrary sequence of 1 to 2000 (rather than a file), the tail recursion optimisation does then kick-in and no stack overflow happens?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that replacing the unparsed-text-lines() call by a sequence dependent on a global parameter won't affect the optimization.

Comment: Confirmed using `xsl:sequence` means both version of the function in the OP work.  Thanks!

Comment: Last point on this - the use of `--generateByteCode:off` is only required for 9.8EE for the named template solution.  The corrected function solutions work in 9.8EE without the switch as per 9.9EE.